# Storing only date part in Cassandra 2 and not the time portion

Tags: date, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I can find the DATE, TIME and TIMESTAMP types in Cassandra 3.
But in Cassandra 2, i can only find the TIMESTAMP type not the others.
How can i store only DATE without the time portion of it in Cassandra 2 ??

```
DATE = Date portion 2018-01-14 (yyyy-MM-dd)
TIME = Time portion 12:12:12 (hh:mm:ss)
TIMESTAMP = Complete timestamp 2018-01-14 12:12:12 (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss)
```

Comment: `date` and `time` both are available in Cassandra-2.2.4. Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using Cassandra 2.1. I think date and time type are not there in 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp type can be entered as an integer for CQL input, or as a string literal in any of the following ISO 8601 formats. The full list and explanations can be found [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html) (the URL contains 3.1 in it, but the contents is for 2.1).

I also did some testing using ccm using Cassandra 2.1.19. I stored it as a timestamp, but retrieved it as date using cqlsh.

The table is like that:

```
create table test1 ( value text, just_date timestamp, PRIMARY KEY (value));
```

I needed to modify my cqlshrc file and added

```
[ui]
time_format = %Y-%m-%d
```

The output looked like this when running the select:

```
value  | just_date
--------+------------
value1 | 2011-01-19
```